# Value does not fall within expected range for dwmapi.dll

Tags: c#

"Value does not fall withing expected range" error appears when I run my program with aero glass. I am using the dwmapi.dll. This is the code:

ON Aero.cs

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Margins
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Right;
        public int Top;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern void DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hwnd, ref Margins margins);

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();
```

ON AddStudent.cs

```
    private const int PaddingCounter = 0;
    private Aero.Margins _newMargins;

    private void SetGlassArea()
    {
        if (Aero.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            _newMargins.Top = Padding.Top;
            _newMargins.Bottom = Padding.Bottom;
            _newMargins.Left = Padding.Left;
            _newMargins.Right = Padding.Right;
            Aero.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref _newMargins);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (Aero.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
            Rectangle clientArea = new Rectangle(_newMargins.Left, _newMargins.Top, this.ClientRectangle.Width - _newMargins.Left -_newMargins.Right,
                this.ClientRectangle.Height - _newMargins.Top - _newMargins.Bottom);
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, clientArea);
        }
    }

    public void ApplyGlassSurface()
    {
        this.Padding = new Padding(PaddingCounter);
        SetGlassArea();
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void AddStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplyGlassSurface();
        webcam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo videoCaptureDevice in webcam)
        {
            comboBoxEx1.Items.Add(videoCaptureDevice.Name);
        }
        comboBoxEx1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

The error points to:

```
Aero.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref _newMargins);
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with it? I know it should work because I've seen a video and it worked for him. Thanks!

Comment: You appear to be making up this code without recourse to the documentation. There are many errors. Read the docs and then try again. An MCVE would be useful. The system tells you that your input is wrong. But you don't show us your input. And you don't check for errors so I can't see where the reported error comes from. I bet your real code differs from the code you show. In short the question is seriously deficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea PreserveSig to true`.

And change Margins to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Margins
{
    public int leftWidth;
    public int rightWidth;
    public int topHeight;
    public int bottomHeight;
}
```